# Increment arrays from existing script

Tags: python, arrays, fuzzing

I have the following script:

```
while a < 17878103347812890000:
    a += 1  # increment

print(id, '#', hex(a)[2:], sep='')
```

I am trying to translate the action of this script to an array:

```
frame = xxxx.fram(xxx, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

My goal for this question is to translate the `while` loop into the array such that it would start at `0000000000000000` and increment to `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: I suspect many potential responders, like myself, got a lost in your explanation. Can you rephrase key phrases like "translate the while loop into the array"? The example with `xxxx`, `fram` and `xxx` is also not clear. Just what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: No worries and thanks,

"frame" is a variable
"xxxx.fram" is actually can.Frame which is the library call for a CAN network message.
"(xxx, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])" sets a message ID and sends the message of 112233445566788 to that message ID.

in the while loop script it starts at 0000000000000001 and adds 1 until it reaches FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I am trying to take what I had previously created in the while loop and incorporate it into the "frame" variable.

My initial thought was:

Answer (score 0):

This is the core of it. I don't know what the `xxx` are or what `id` is in the original code... but this is it

```
result = [ '#'+ hex(a)[2:] for a in range(0,17878103347812890000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

(Your code is broken so I'll fix the accidental indentation of the third line being pushed inwards)

Okay so lets first explain what the initial function is doing then we can work on a solution :).  So what it is doing is converting all the integer values from 0 to 17878103347812890000 to hexadecimal then printing them, so lets break up the code;

- `while a < 17878103347812890000:` loops through all the integer values
- `a += 1` just is the other part of the loop that increments it upwards
- `print(id, '#', hex(a)[2:], sep='')` calls three separate print calls similar to adding a '+' between them

  - `id` I'm gonna ignore since you didn't add any details on what that is
  - `hex(a)[2:]` converts the number to hexadecimal then skips the `0x` part (starting at second index)
  - `sep=''` stops the separator from printing a line

Okay so now to push this downwards first we make it a for loop (important);

```
for a in range(0, 17878103347812890000):
  print(id, '#', hex(a)[2:], sep='')
```

Now we make it create an array of a single string with those details

```
arrayOfLines = [ str(id) + '#' + hex(a)[2:] for a in range(0, 17878103347812890000) ]
```

> `str(id)` is just incase id isn't already a string, if it is then remove the `str(...)` part and just have `id +

Note: `str(id) + '#' + hex(a)[2:] for a in range(0, 17878103347812890000)` is just a for loop but its called 'list comprehension' (you are well comprehending a list structure from a preset condition) so it creates a list of strings (or text) so now you want to print that together so we use `.join` so we write;

```
arrayOfLines = [ str(id) + '#' + str(hex(a)[2:]) for a in range(0, 17878103347812890000) ]
print("\n".join(arrayOfLines))
```

As a one liner;

```
print("\n".join([ str(id) + '#' + str(hex(a)[2:]) for a in range(0, 500)]))
```